# Can i restrict a App (which is deployed to our app catalog) from being added inside certain site collections

Tags: development, web-part, app, sharepoint-framework

I have developed a client-side web-part by following steps simialr to those mentioned on this link [Deploy your client-side web part to a SharePoint page (Hello World part 3)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page)

then i deploy the web part to our app catalog site collection. then inside any site collection i can go to >> site content >> Add App >> i can add the web-part. but my question is if I can restrict the App from being added to only certain site collections? in other words to only show the App (when we want to add a new app) inside certain site collections only. is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Site collection app catalog for this capability.

Currently, when you upload the app it gets uploaded to the tenant app catalog.

Once, you enable the site collection app catalog feature, you can then upload the app to that particular site collection's app catalog which will ensure that the app is available to only to that particular site collection.

You need to run the below commands to enable it. Ensure that you are SharePoint admin while executing it, else it will throw error :

```
Connect-SPOService -Url "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com"

$site = Get-SPOSite https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSiteCollection

Add-SPOSiteCollectionAppCatalog -Site $site
```

Reference - [Use the site collection app catalog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog)

Comment: hey @SharePointTestDev, hope this helps you find an answer to your question. You can accept it as answer which will help us and remove it from the list of unanswered questions :) Thanks !